# Why does Entity sometimes need a "url" parameter and sometimes not?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to setup a DataImportHandler and upon trying to do a full import I get this error:

> SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: SolrEntityProcessor: parameter 'url' is required Processing Document # 1

I see in the example data-config.xml that come with solr sometimes Entity has the url parameter and sometimes it doesn't. If it is required why do some of the examples not have it?

What URL is it looking for?

The documentation actually doesn't show "url" as a required parameter for SqlEntityProcessor

> For SqlEntityProcessor the entity attributes are :
>   query (required) : The sql string using which to query the db
>   deltaQuery : Only used in delta-import
>   parentDeltaQuery : Only used in delta-import
>   deletedPkQuery : Only used in delta-import
>   deltaImportQuery : (Only used in delta-import) . If this is not present , DIH tries to construct the import query by(after identifying the delta) modifying the 'query' (this is error prone). There is a namespace ${dataimporter.delta.} which can be used in this query. e.g: select * from tbl where id=${dataimporter.delta.id}   Solr1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specific `EntityProcessor` implementation you use. Every `EntityProcessor` has its own entity attributes. `SQLEntityProcessor` doesn't need an url parameter because it relies on the [`dataSource`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DataSource) element to get the information needed to connect to the database, while for example the `SolrEntityProcessor` doesn't need the `dataSource` element but relies on the `url` attribute to get the url of the Solr instance from which import data.
There are different `DataSource` implementations as well, if you look at [`JdbcDataSource`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#jdbcdatasource) you'll see it requires the url parameter itself.

Comment: I had meant to use SqlEntityProcessor, but I guess I went all cross-eyed and typed SolrEntityProcessor instead, so that is why it told me I needed a url param. Changed it to SqlEntityProcessor and now all is well.